# UINavigationController, Button Click to Open URL in WebView, Located in Different View

Tags: iphone, c, xcode

So basically I want a UITableView to display a bunch of websites in the RootView. Then from there, using the UINavigationController, I would like to open a different view (WebViewController) and load the URL specified in the button, in the UIWebView.

What would be the best way to do this?

**EDIT:** Okay so there are basically two views. **The first view** is the RootViewController, which is includes the UINavigationController. Basically this will include some buttons (that have custom URL's already assigned to them) that will change & load the URL in the webView using the following.

```
-(IBAction)linkButton:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://URL_HERE.com"];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

**The second view** will be called the "CodeView" and it will include the UIWebView object dubbed *webView*.

So what I'm trying to accomplish is this: After clicking on one of the buttons in the *RootViewController*, it will switch to the *CodeView* and load whatever URL has been assigned to the button itself, in the UIWebView object. Then of course, have the option to return to the *RootViewController* via the UINavigationController, which is just common sense when it comes to using a Navigation Controller.

Comment: Just added more information above :) ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have to put the root view inside a navigation controller (i suupose you are already doing this) then for each button you tap you could create a new codeview with the url and push it to the navigation controller.

This way you could have your webview inside the codeview. Did i miss something?